# How can i update subversion version in Intellij 2018.2 on linux?

Tags: intellij-idea, svn, tortoisesvn

How can i update subversion version in Intellij 2018.2 on linux? currently my svn version is 1.6 which intellij 2018 does not support.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ relies on the command line svn client. There is no built-in one. So you just need to update the svn client you have in the system, or install a different one, and tell IntelliJ to use it by specifying the path to the desired svn client in Settings | Version control | Subversion